# Initialising static multi-dimensional null-terminated arrays

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, static

I'd like to initialise a static array which is null-terminated and contains static null-terminated arrays. I'd also like to be able to print all of the contents at a later point.

Here's the code I've got so far, **obviously the initialisation and datatypes are not correct**:

```
void print_commands(char *commands[][])
{
    int i, j;
    char *command[];

    for(i = 0; commands[][i] != NULL; i++)
    {
        command = commands[][i];
        printf("Command #%d: %s\n", i, command[0]);
        for(j = 1; command[j] != NULL; j++)
        {
            printf("Argument #%d: %s\n", j, command[j]);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *commands[][5] = {
        {"less", 0}, 
        {"sort", 0}, 
        {"cat", "my.txt", 0},
        {"echo", "hello", 0}, 
        NULL};

    print_commands(commands);

    exit( 0 );
}
```

How would I go about properly initialising and using this kind of data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void print_commands(char **commands[])
{
    int i, j;
    char **command;

    for(i = 0; commands[i] != NULL; i++)
    {
        command = commands[i];
        printf("Command #%d: %s\n", i, command[0]);
        for(j = 1; command[j] != NULL; j++)
        {
            printf("Argument #%d: %s\n", j, command[j]);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char **commands[] = {
        (char*[]){"less", 0}, 
        (char*[]){"sort", 0}, 
        (char*[]){"cat", "my.txt", 0},
        (char*[]){"echo", "hello", 0}, 
        NULL};

    print_commands(commands);

    exit( 0 );
}
```

or

```
void print_commands(char *commands[][5])
{
    int i, j;
    char **command;

    for(i = 0; *commands[i] != NULL; i++)
    {
        command = commands[i];
        printf("Command #%d: %s\n", i, command[0]);
        for(j = 1; command[j] != NULL; j++)
        {
            printf("Argument #%d: %s\n", j, command[j]);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *commands[][5] = {
        {"less", 0}, 
        {"sort", 0}, 
        {"cat", "my.txt", 0},
        {"echo", "hello", 0}, 
        { NULL }
    };

    print_commands(commands);

    exit( 0 );
}
```

Comment: I'd go with the second version since it is more readable and less confusing than the array of pointer-to-pointer to compound literals. Also, `int i ... for(i = 0` suggests that the OP might be using C90 and then compound literals won't work.

Comment: That's right. The first version assumes the c99 compiler. (E.g. can't compile with VC10)

Answer (score 2):

Since arrays are not pointers, you can't initialize an array with `NULL`. Why not choose the so common and idiomatic principle of **the all-zero struct?**

```
char *commands[][5] = {
    { "less", NULL },
    { "sort", NULL },
    { "cat", "my.txt", NULL },
    { "echo", "hello", NULL },
    { NULL }
};
```